# Old Answers Coming up as Late Answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

I was just reviewing some Late Answers and came across [**this one**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14388/7424) in the list.

[image]

Clearly this is not a new user's answer to an old question.  It's an *old* answer to an old question.

This is also the second answer that was in the list from this user.  Both were answered on the same date?  What's going on here?

The reviews:

- https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/24865
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/24866

Answer (score 4):

I answered this [over at the corresponding question on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213020/late-late-answer), but to save you the travel time:

Answers enter the Late Answers queue if they are posted over 30 days after the question was posted, *and* the post author has less than 10 reputation. If someone posts a late answer while above 10 reputation at the time, their post doesn't get entered into the queue. However, if they drop below 10 reputation (as happened in both instances you linked here), their post now qualifies and is entered into the queue.